# Why don't I have Pulse audio?

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, headphones

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18 on a cheapo laptop.

I tried to run *Spotify* both via *Firefox* where it gave me a warning that *PulseAudio* may not be installed.

To make sure this wasn't just *Firefox*, I tried the *Spotify* desktop app but I found the songs skipped instantly to the next without playing until it reached the end of a playlist.

In my sound settings everything is **greyed out** and I see no selection for either the laptop's speakers or headphones when plugged in. Looking through questions on *PulseAudio* not working, I've found that I don't actually appear to have the .pulseAudio directory.

So I reinstalled Ubuntu, and I still don't have PulseAudio. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: 1. I run pulseaudio and I don't have a .pulseaudio directory. 2. May be it's your sound card that is not recognised and/or need proprietary drivers. What is the output of `lshw -class multimedia` ?. Add it to your question by editing it.

Comment: The only reason you would need pulse audio, would be if you had multiple users playing audio, alsa should work just as good if not better, alsamixer ?